# jqgrid : How to do pagination with indexeddb (client side data base)

Tags: jqgrid, indexeddb

I am working on indexeddb (local client side data base). I have written the jqgrid to render the data.
I am not able to do pagination.

My requirement is :
in jqgrid, dataType is local because it is not fetching the data from server.
And I don't wants to cache all records with jqgrid.
let say in index db 100 records and on first load, I wants to load 10 records only. when user press next button, i should fetch the next 10 records from indexedDB (this is client side data base) and display.

I can able to fetch the data from indexeddb, only problem with jqgrid.

Can you please help me.

Thanks & Regards,
Brijesh Baser

Comment: Hey check out jsstore - http://jsstore.net/. It provides skip and limit option for pagination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

indexedDB does not provide an equivalent of SQL limit. The only way to stop iterating is to maintain a counter variable and check if it was reached. Something like this:

```
var counter = 0;
var limit = 10;
function query() {
  db.transaction('').objectStore().openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if(cursor) {
      var value = cursor.value;
      console.log(value);
      counter++;
      if(counter < limit) {
        // only continue if under limit
        cursor.continue();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To go to the next page, you want to use IDBCursor.prototype.advance, and pass in the amount of objects to skip, such as 10. Something like this:

```
function query() {
  var advanced = false;
  db.transaction('').objectStore().openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;

    if(!cursor) {
      return;
    }

    if(!advanced) {
      advanced = true;
      cursor.advance(10);
      return;
    }

    var value = cursor.value;
    console.log(value);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh for sharing this info. This is useful for indexed DB.

But My probleam is pagination in jqgrid.
If I declare data type local and pass the all object to jqgrid, it is doing itself pagination. But I wants to provide only 10 records and provide the information of total no of record (e.g. 1000) when user click next button, I should get the call back.
But when I provide 10 records in jqgrid, internally total no Of records sets 10 only.

Can you please help me in term of jqgrid.